# Waiting a few callbacks from MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I have a few `.find()` queries and I'm not sure what's a good way to wait for all callbacks to finish.

I mean, I could do some counter and increment it on each callback function and check on it every time it changes, but I feel like this is really durty.

Then there are some libraries like `async` and `Q`, but I'm not really sure I want to use them *just* to wait for a few callbacks.

So, my question is: Have you suffered the same problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, these libraries are there to solve exactly this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a counter that increases every time the callback is called is not dirty, but what most libraries does in the back somehow. However this is one way to wait for a few callbacks using async:

```
async.parallel({
  ppl: Person.find.bind(Person, { status: 1 }),
  catz: Cat.find.bind(Cat, { meow: 2 })
},
function (err, result) {
  console.log(result.ppl, result.catz);
});
```

.bind() is just a shortcut for:

```
function (next) {
  People.find({ status: 1}, next);
}
```

Depending on your situation you might want to use async.series, .each or .waterfall instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use async :)